# Android: How to access internet from a class?

Tags: android

My project runs a service which instantiates a class called Connect (its neither an Activity or a Service).

I need to access Internet through class Connect.

How should i proceed?

Do i need to mention something in manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use internet in your app, you need this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

It doesn't matter if it's in a service/activity or just a class you call.